# give different pch to names in scatter plot R?

Tags: r

I have these:

```
 x=c(2,1,5,2)  ; y=c(6,11,7,3)
 x1=c(7,6,7,3)  ; y1=c(3,9,4,3)
 names(y1) = c("B", "C","A","D");  names(x1) = c("A", "B","C","D")
 names(y) = c("C", "B","A","D");names(x) = c("D", "A","B","D")
 plot(x1,y1,col="green")
```

The problem here is that it takes first value of x1 (7) and first value of y1 (3) and plot them. Which means “A” and “B”. I would like the correspondence to be A from x1 (7) should be plot with A from y1 (4).

Also I want to give different pch for each letter and plot the legend (in the plot all are dots (circles)).

Any hnts on this?

Comment: You should arrange your data into a single data.frame and then plot that, rather than plotting multiple vectors

Comment: To add points to an existing plot, use the `points` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend storing your data in data frames, not separate vectors. In this case, using data frames makes it easy to `merge` your x and y data so that they line up by name:

```
dx = data.frame(name = names(x1), x1 = x1)
dy = data.frame(name = names(y1), y1 = y1)
d = merge(dx, dy)
d
#   name x1 y1
# 1    A  7  4
# 2    B  6  3
# 3    C  7  9
# 4    D  3  3
```

Then plotting works pretty easily, again using the data frame:

```
with(d, plot(x1,y1,col="green", pch = as.integer(name)))
```

[image]

I'll leave adding the legend to you - just search for "how to add a legend to a plot in R", or look at `?legend`.

As a side-note, `ggplot2` is very popular for plotting. It automatically adds legends, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x1, y = y1, shape = name)) +
    geom_point(color = "green") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]